# How to wait for other python processes to put string into queue before putting next item into queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a small example for my problem:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def test_1(q,j):
    for i in range(10):
        q.put('test_{}: '.format(j) + str(i),block=False)



q = Queue()
p1 = Process(target=test_1, args=(q,1))
p2 = Process(target=test_1, args=(q,2))
p1.start()
p2.start()

with open('test1.txt', 'w') as file:
    while p1.is_alive() or p2.is_alive() or not q.empty():
        try:
            value = q.get(timeout = 1)
            file.write(value + '\n')
        except Exception as qe:
            print("Empty Queue or dead process")

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Then my output is like:

```
test_1: 0
test_1: 1
test_1: 2
test_1: 3
test_1: 4
test_1: 5
test_1: 6
test_1: 7
test_1: 8
test_1: 9
test_2: 0
test_2: 1
test_2: 2
test_2: 3
test_2: 4
test_2: 5
test_2: 6
test_2: 7
test_2: 8
test_2: 9
```

How can I get an output like:

```
test_1: 0
test_2: 0
test_1: 1
test_2: 1
test_1: 2
test_2: 2
.
.
.
```

and so on.

Would be cool if somebody could help me with that.

For your interest, I would like to use that later to match input- and output-vectors as training data for a machine learning approach.

Thanks in advance,

Yaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when I want to use multithreading with python I use ``ThreadPool```
I'm not sure that's really what you want but you can easly get your result using this function as written here:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from psutil import cpu_count

def test_1(thread):
    for i in range(10):
        string = ('test_{}: '.format(thread) + str(i))
        print(string)

pool = ThreadPool(processes=cpu_count(logical=True))

lines_async = pool.apply_async(test_1, args=([1]))
lines_async2 = pool.apply_async(test_1, args=([2]))
lines_async.get()
lines_async2.get()
```

the result is here :

```py
test_1: 0
test_2: 0
test_1: 1
test_2: 1
test_1: 2
test_2: 2
test_1: 3
test_2: 3
test_1: 4
test_2: 4
test_1: 5
test_2: 5
test_1: 6
test_2: 6
test_1: 7
test_2: 7
test_2: 8
test_1: 8
test_2: 9
test_1: 9
```

but it's a different approach than the one you carried out

EDIT: if you want to get the value of the function you can use it :

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from psutil import cpu_count

pool = ThreadPool(processes=cpu_count(logical=True))

def test_1(thread, i):
    string = ('test_{}: '.format(thread) + str(i))
    return string

for i in range(10):
    lines_async = pool.apply_async(test_1, args=([1,i]))
    lines_async2 = pool.apply_async(test_1, args=([2,i]))
    string1 = lines_async.get()
    string2 = lines_async2.get()
    print(string1)
    print(string2)
```

which is more similar than what you want and gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a concurrency based solution (a real concurrency problem/solution):

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue
from threading import Thread, Lock, Condition


def test_1(q,j,sem,other_has_writen,th):
    for i in range(10):
        # print("Th%i adquires conditional sem"%j)
        other_has_writen.acquire()
        # print("Th%i th=%i"%(j,th[0]))
        if th[0]!=j:
            # print("Th%i on IF"%j)
            # print("Th%i adquires sem"%j)
            sem.acquire()
            th[0] = j
            # print("Th%i releases sem"%j)
            sem.release()
            # print("Th%i th_after=%i"%(j,th[0]))
            # print("Th%i prints -----> %i"%(j,i))
            q.put('test_{}: '.format(j) + str(i),block=False)
            other_has_writen.notify_all()
        else:
            # print("Th%i waits"%j)
            other_has_writen.wait()
            q.put('test_{}: '.format(j) + str(i),block=False)
        other_has_writen.release()
        # print("Th%i releases conditional sem"%j)
    # other_has_writen.notify_all()
        
th = [1]
sem = Lock()
other_has_writen = Condition()
q = Queue()
p1 = Thread(target=test_1, args=(q,1,sem,other_has_writen,th))
p2 = Thread(target=test_1, args=(q,2,sem,other_has_writen,th))
p1.start()
p2.start()

# print('------- Program continues -------')

with open('test1.txt', 'w') as file:
    while p1.is_alive() or p2.is_alive() or not q.empty():
        try:
            value = q.get(timeout = 1)
            file.write(value + '\n')
        except Exception as qe:
            print("Empty Queue or dead process")

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Output will be always alternated as you need the other thread to notify he has finished writing:

```sh
test_2: 0
test_1: 0
test_1: 1
test_2: 1
test_2: 2
test_1: 2
test_1: 3
test_2: 3
test_2: 4
test_1: 4
test_1: 5
test_2: 5
test_2: 6
test_1: 6
test_1: 7
test_2: 7
test_2: 8
test_1: 8
test_1: 9
test_2: 9
```